# Ajax POST request works on localhost, but not on website

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on a project where I can search up chemical compounds.

I have an autocomplete feature to the searchbar, but it appears an error when I hosted the website. This is the error I got:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
at ajax_request.onreadystatechange

Here is the front-end page:

```
function autocomplete(inp) {
        /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
        the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
        var currentFocus;

        /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
        inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
            var a, b, i, val = this.value;
            /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
            closeAllLists();
            if (!val) {
                return false;
            }

            currentFocus = -1;
            /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
            a = document.createElement("DIV");
            a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
            a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
            /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
            this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

            // Check if the user input is at least one character
            if (val.length >= 1) {
                // Create form data to submit with php

                var form_data = new FormData();

                form_data.append('query', val);

                // Create ajax request
                var ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                ajax_request.open('POST', 'process_data.php', true);
                ajax_request.send(form_data);


                ajax_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (ajax_request.readyState == 4 && ajax_request.status == 200) {

                        // Store the matching compounds in an array
                        var arr = JSON.parse(ajax_request.responseText);

                        console.log(arr);

                        /*for each item in the array...*/
                        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                            /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/

                            /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
                            b = document.createElement("DIV");
                            /*make the matching letters bold:*/
                            b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].title.substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                            b.innerHTML += arr[i].title.substr(val.length);
                            b.innerHTML += " - " + arr[i].name;
                            /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
                            b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i].title + "'>";
                            /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
                            b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                                /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                                inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                                /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                                (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                                closeAllLists();
                            });
                            a.appendChild(b);

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

And here is the back-end code (php) process_data.php:

```
<?php

include("path.php");
include(ROOT_PATH . '/app/database/mysqli.connect.php');
include(ROOT_PATH . '/app/database/db.php');


if (isset($_POST["query"])) { 

    $query = $_POST['query'];

    $result = selectALL("formulae", ['enabled' => 1]);

    $autocompleteResult = array();
    if ($result) {
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            //array_push($autocompleteResult, );
            $autocompleteResult[$row['id']]['title'] = strip_tags($row["title"]);
            $autocompleteResult[$row['id']]['name'] = $row["name"];
        }
    }

    $autocompleteResult = array_values($autocompleteResult);

    $listResult = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($autocompleteResult); $i++) {
        if (strtoupper(substr($autocompleteResult[$i]['title'], 0, strlen($query))) == strtoupper($query) || strtoupper(substr($autocompleteResult[$i]['name'], 0, strlen($query))) == strtoupper($query)) {
            $listResult[$i]['title'] = $autocompleteResult[$i]["title"];
            $listResult[$i]['name'] = $autocompleteResult[$i]["name"];
        }
    }

    $listResult = array_values($listResult);

    echo json_encode($listResult);
}
```

Thank you for helping me in advance!

I tried to change the javascript to see if there were something wrong there, and the back-end script which filters the search

Debugging details:
[image]

Console
[image]

Comment: Start by checking what response the request actually got, using your browser dev tools (network panel.)

Comment: Sounds like maybe you didn't get any results, or an error occurred instead. As above, do some basic debugging by using the browser's tools to see what's actually happening to the request, and also check things like the PHP error log. If you have code which works in one environment but not another, then the code alone is rarely going to be the main issue, or be sufficient for us to diagnose a problem from. You have to investigate environment issues by looking in detail at what happens when you try to execute it in the problem environment.

Comment: I got 301 and 200

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Neither `301` nor `200` are valid JSON responses. Also, I doubt that the code you've shared would produce such an output

Comment: `I got 301 and 200`... for which request(s)? Are you saying the ajax request got redirected? Also what was the _content_ of the final response? Presumably it's empty and/or doesn't contain (purely) JSON. Click into each request and look at the raw response data too. And yeah, it's better if you [edit] your question and put all the debugging info coherently in one place. Thanks.

Comment: @NicoHaase I think these are HTTP status codes. Which is part of the story, but not the whole story obviously.

Comment: The best place to look is Network tab in your browser developer tools. Click your result and go to `Response` tab and check what response you got from API. I am 100% sure its not a valid JSON. Check why its not a valid JSON. Is PHP echoing anything else than `listResult` ?

Comment: Remember to check your PHP error log on the server, too. (If PHP error logging isn't enabled, speak to the hosting company and get it enabled)

Comment: I did not get any responses from the network tab, it was empty, will check on php error logging

Comment: Does the call to process_data.php return any data in its Response tab?

Comment: Also is the last request to `/process_data` a GET or a POST? Does the payload still contain your `query` data? Does that URL still cause `process_data.php` to be executed? If it's a GET, and/or the query data is missing, then obviously `if (isset($_POST["query"]))` would be false and in that instance your code returns no data at all.

Comment: But also why are you redirecting _away_ from the .php file? Have you got some htaccess rules in place perhaps which are supposed to create "nice" URLs? And if so, why don't you have the same redirect rules in your localhost? You have to make sure the environments have the same setup, to avoid any unexpected problems like this when you deploy to the website server.

Comment: Yes I do have .htaccess rules to display "nice" urls, but that is the same for the local and uploaded website. Will try without htaccess

Comment: "it was empty" - that sounds strange. According to the screenshot, the first response had a size of 297 bytes

Comment: `that is the same for the local`...the results you're getting suggest strongly that it isn't

Comment: That actually worked, I removed the htaccess rules, and it does now work, thank you so much, I have always been using these lines, so I thought why shouldn't it be nice to use.

Comment: No worries. You should likely compare the behaviour very closely with your local environment, to see if that is in fact doing any of this redirecting etc. It sounds like maybe that isn't actually happening in your local - or if it is, it might be doing it differently, in a way that works.

Comment: Yes apparently it does it differently :)

Answer (score 1):

Removed .htaccess rules that displays "nice" urls. That made the back-end not redirect. And it now works. Suggestion by @ADyson

> But also why are you redirecting away from the .php file? Have you got some htaccess rules in place perhaps which are supposed to create "nice" URLs? And if so, why don't you have the same redirect rules in your localhost? You have to make sure the environments have the same setup, to avoid any unexpected problems like this when you deploy to the website server.